# Set default first row in sql in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;

CLOUMN_NAME
1st
2nd
3rd
```

Am getting the output when I run this query.

I need to have a ***default value for 'Please Select' as first row always*** even column holds the empty or null value of the result set.

Exptected Result

```
CLOUMN_NAME
Please Select
1st
2nd
3rd
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many column you need to return only on or more than one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 'please select' col_name
union all
select col_name::text FROM MY_TABLE;
```

---

Edit : as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369423/set-default-first-row-in-sql-in-postgres/30371954?noredirect=1#comment48950849_30371954) comment

In your case you need to use `order by` in **second** *select statement*

```
select 'please select' col_name 
union all
(select col_name::text FROM MY_TABLE order by 1)
```

[**sqlfiddle - demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f46b2/1)

you need to convert *column*  in that table(`MY_TABLE`) to text if that column is not a `Text`,`varchar`

Comment: Works fine but fails in a scenario.If the column holds the empty value then the empty value is coming first while sorting the.data. My requirement is that whatever the column data it may have 'Please Select' value should come first.

Comment: There is no real order here. Order not guaranteed by UNION.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `union all` as below

```
SELECT 'Please Select' as CLOUMN_NAME 
union all
SELECT cast(CLOUMN_NAME as varchar) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

I'm not sure what type is `CLOUMN_NAME` but should be `string` type because in first query we return this type.

Comment: There is no order here... it could be in any order. Order not guaranteed by UNION.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stable sort you need some kind of criteria to distinguish the "first" row from the "real" ones:

```
select column_name
from (
  select 'please select' as column_name, 0 as sort_order
  union all
  select column_name, 1 as sort_order
  FROM MY_TABLE
) t
order by sort_order;
```

Note that the sort order for the actual data is undefined in this case because all rows from the table get the same "sort_order" value. If you e.g. want the real rows to be sorted alphabetically, you can add the display column to the order by: `order by sort_order, column_name.

The above assumes that `my_table.column_name` is a character data type. If it is not, you need some type casting.

Comment: This is the correct answer because it uses correct ordering